# Should an implicit declaration return an error

Tags: c, gcc

consider the following test program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
   double t = nan(NULL);
   printf("%g\n",t);
   return 0;
}
```

compile with

```
/usr/local/bin/gcc  -lm -o test test.c
```

output is NaN as expected.
However if I mistype or make a mistake and leave out the

```
#include <math.h>
```

it compiles fine, no errors, no warnings but gives the output of 0

if I compile with the `-Wall` it does give the warning warning: implicit declaration of function `nan' though this behaviour seems worthy of something more than a warning. Is there any point to not stopping compilation on this?  and does anyone have any suggestions as to how to stop this causing a major headache on rather larger files?

Comment: Read the compiler manual to learn how to make it give you proper diagnostics. For example, you forgot `-pedantic`.

Comment: You should really never run GCC without -Wall.

Comment: "and does anyone have any suggestions as to how to stop this causing a major headache on rather larger files?" - use `-Werror` too.

Comment: @kerrekSB -pedantic doesn't seem to make any difference to this

Comment: `-std=gnu99 -Wall -Werror -Wextra` or `-std=c99 -Wall -Werror -Wextra`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation of gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html) is crystal clear on this subject:

> C99 is substantially completely supported as of GCC 4.5 (with -std=c99
>   -pedantic-errors used) [...]

Indeed, you get a compile error if you use **both** `-std=c99` and `-pedantic-errors`.

---

Although I am still wondering how you got the results you wrote. I get a very different behavior with gcc 4.7.2. Your code gives the followings:

> $ gcc -Wall -std=c99 -pedantic-errors bug.c -lm
>   bug.c: In function ‘main’:
>   bug.c:7:4: warning: null argument where non-null required (argument 1) [-Wnonnull]

and the generated executable crashes with a segfault on my machine.

However, if I change `double t = nan(NULL);` to `double t = nan("");` then it compiles. If I comment out the `#include <math.h>` and omit the `-pedantic-errors` flag then it even compiles and prints `nan`. Both are different from what you write. Which version of gcc are you using?

Comment: What I said in my earlier comments to @H2CO3 is, although C99 prohibits the implicit declarations, the code will compile with `-std=C99 -Wall -pedantic` (with warnings off course). Note: I am not using `Werror` or `-pedantic-errors` here. But it should not compile as it is prohibited by the standard. (Compiled on GCC-4.8.1).

Comment: @haccks And it doesn't compile if you pass the right flags. You only need to read the first sentence in the doc to figure out which flags are required to enforce C99 (`-std=c99` and `-pedantic-errors`).

Comment: In fact I do not have C99 draft but C11. It is not mentioned there.

Comment: @haccks I am afraid I don't follow. I was referring to the doc of GCC.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Never knew that before that `-pedantic-errors` is necessary to enforce C99.

Comment: @haccks Me either until today. :) I personally find it confusing that enforcing a standard requires two flags. Well, at least it is documented...

Answer (score 9):

> Should an implicit declaration return an error

Yes. Implicit declarations were "valid" (but still problematic, confusing and bad practice) in C89, but in C99 and C11, they are prohibited.

C99, 6.5.1.2:

> An identifier is a primary expression, provided it has been declared as designating an object (in which case it is an lvalue) or a function (in which case it is a function designator).<sup>79</sup>
>
> 79) Thus, an undeclared identifier is a violation of the syntax.

What confuses you is that GCC and clang (given the command line switches used, I think you are using one of these) **are not conforming C implementations by default,** without additional strict flags such as `-Werror -pedantic -pedantic-errors`.

Comment: But C99 allows implicit declaration.

Comment: @haccks No. From where did you get that idea?

Comment: I compiled many time this code in c99 mode: `main(){printf("Hello World");}`! (Disclaimer: Do not turn on your `Werror` flag).

Comment: @haccks Ah OK. Well, if it is explicitly required to omit `-Werror`, then again, GCC is non-conforming. So is your program in C99.

Comment: Setting the compilation flag -std=c99 still only turns it into a warning.

Comment: @haccks I'm sorry but I'm not interested in that bullshit. Without `-Wall -pedantic -Werror`, GCC is not conforming, and it doesn't matter  what it compiles and what it doesn't. C99 explicitly prohibits implicit declarations, and a shitty implementation doesn't change that fact. **Not even if you insist** because you didn't read the standard.

Comment: @camelccc; Yes you are right. It will not affect until you turn your `Werror` flag on.

Comment: @H2CO3; The above code will compile (with warnings) with `-Wall -pedantic` in C99 mode.

Comment: @haccks Why do you keep saying that "but it compiles but it compiles but it compiles but it compiles"? I don't care. Nobody cares. The standard doesn't care. It shouldn't compile. If it compiles, then your compiler is crap (yes, I'm saying that GCC is crap and Clang is crap). Period. Read the standard if you don't believe me. Go ask the standard committee.

Comment: @H2CO3; Ummm. I don't know GCC is crap or not but somehow, although standard prohibit this, it.....! :). (But some times I do care why?). By the way now the quote `C99, 6.5.1.2:`  is tempting me to vote you up as I am 100% agreed with standard in this case.

Comment: @haccks I suspect spite (that's the general reason). I was actually pretty surprised that I wasn't really bothered by the downvote this time :D

Comment: By the way it may leads to be a [misunderstanding](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20874054/2455888). Better to clarify :) (Hope you don't mind)

Comment: @H2CO3 gcc isn't crap. Please read my answer. Even if you think it's crap, please submit a bugreport if you think you have found a bug. (I personally think gcc, despite its quirks, is a good compiler.)

Comment: @haccks gcc isn't crap. Please read my answer. Even if you think it's crap, please submit a bugreport if you think you have found a bug. (I personally think gcc, despite its quirks, is a good compiler.)

Comment: @Ali Of course it is not crap. But what do I say to someone who doesn't believe the standard, only his (non-conformant) compiler? Also, whatever GCC's documentation says is unimportant in the sense that it doesn't change what conforms to C99 and what does not.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes, I agree with the latter. My point is that the code compiled because haccks didn't bother to read *the very first sentence in the doc* of the c99 features and used the compiler wrong. GCC **is** standard conforming if used properly. (Well, yeah, modulo bugs.)

Comment: @H2CO3; *who doesn't believe the standard*: I do believe in standard, of course!

Comment: @haccks Sorry for the assumption. I *honestly* didn't know what you found wrong or incorrect in what I said (since you appeared that you treated the compiler as if it dictated the language spec). But anyway, there's no confusion anymore. Peace.